# How to create two routes in one block in grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to catch 2 similar route in one action block. In Rails5 I can do that easily. I first declare this:

```
get ':folder/:file' => 'get#index', :file => /.*/, :folder => /.*/
get ':file' => 'get#index', :file => /.*/
```

This allows me to catch `:folder` as much as folder can be like `a/b/c/d...` and `:file` at end one last filename. Second one also allow me to only catch filenames. **And both routes target to same action.**

However, In Grape because it is declared as blocks rather than route to method definitions, I have to write same block twice...

Is there any way to catch both `/as/many/folder/and/file.ext` and just `/file.ext` in one route parameter? I tried optional params, requirements. None of them worked.

The reason behind I use `:folder/:file` (twice regexp) is i can grab `:folder` param and `:file` param separately without manually splitting them.

```
get ':folder/:file', requirements: { file: /.*/, folder: /.*/ } do
  # params[:folder] and params[:file]
end

get ':file', requirements: { file: /.*/ } do
  # params[:file]. [:folder is empty.]
end
```

^^ I want to make them one single route. If folder exists (nested) then it will grab in folder param otherwise folder will be nil.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I've found the answer by trying and looking to refdocs.

```
get '(:folder/):file', requirements: {  folder: /.*/, file: /.*/ } do
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
desc 'Create transaction'
params do
  requires :id, type: String
  requires :from_, type: String
end
post ['/:id/addresses/:from_/transactions', '/:id/transactions'] do

end
```

Routes:

```
/api/v1/wallets/:id/addresses/:from_/transactions  
/api/v1/wallets/:id/transactions
```